# Calculating a line integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Calculate $\int_\gamma f(t) dt$ where $f(t) = t^2$ and $\gamma $ is
>   the semi circle from $i$ to $-i$ (counter clockwise)

I set $\gamma : \left[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right] \rightarrow  \mathbb{C} = e^{ix}$ (unit circle)

and

$\int_\gamma f(t) dt =^{\text{def}} \int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\frac{3\pi}{2}f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \;dt = \int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\frac{3\pi}{2} (e^{iz})^2 \cdot (ie^{iz}) = \left[\frac{1}{3}e^{3iz}\right]_\frac{\pi}{2}^\frac{3\pi}{2} 
$ $= \frac{1}{3}e^{2\pi i} - \frac{1}{3} e^{\frac{3}{2}\pi i} 
= \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3} -i = $ ?

Did I make any mistake? Can the result be simplified?

Comment: Well, since $\;e^{2\pi i}=1\;,\;\;e^{\frac32\pi i}=-i\;$ , I'd say the result can be put in a slighter nicer, easy-to-grasp form, indeed.

Comment: Watch the integration variables. If you use $t$ as the real parameter of $\gamma$, then you need to use a different variable like $z$ for the complex variable in the line integral.

Comment: @DavidH thanks, you're right, I renamed it. Are there any other mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wolf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BE%5E%282%20I%20x%29%20D%5BE%5E%28I%20x%29,%20x%5D,%20%7Bx,%20Pi/2,%203%20Pi/2%7D%5D&dataset=), the answer is $\frac {2i}{3}$. You might particularly want to check it here.
$$\left[\frac{1}{3}e^{3iz}\right]_\frac{\pi}{2}^\frac{3\pi}{2} = \frac 1 3 \left( e^{i \frac {9\pi} 2} - e^{i \frac {3\pi} 2}\right) = \frac{2i}{3}$$